# How do I denote a set of function values

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to denote the set of values given by the function $h(v, k)$ for all $v \in \{0, 1\}$ and $k \in \{0, 1, ..., 2^K-1\}$.

I was thinking something like this:
$$H = \{ h(v, k) : v \in \{0, 1\}, k \in \{0, 1, ..., 2^{K}-1\}\}$$

But I don't think this is the correct way of doing it. How would you write this?

Comment: I think your notation is fine; it certainly is understandable and it means what you are saying in English.

Comment: I'm asking because I've never seen a function on the left hand side in a set-builder notation.

Answer (score 0):

Additional note: Your set $H$ is the [image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29) of the function $h: \{0,1\} \times \{0,1,\ldots,2^K-1\} \rightarrow Y$ (whereby $Y$ is the  [codomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain)  of $h$). So you can also write $h(\{0,1\} \times \{0,1,\ldots,2^K-1\})$ or $\operatorname{im}(h)$ for your set $H$.